# snake game with allegro

Tags: c, allegro

hi can someone please help me i m trying to code a snake game with allegro(in ubuntu) i managed to write this code but it doesn't work and i cant seem to find the problem when i compile it appears to be alright but when i execute some type of memory issue (memory map)appears and then nothing happens when i execute many times in a row it begins but crashes few moments later

```
#include <allegro.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct snake_node
    {
    int dir;
    int x;
    int y;
    struct snake_node * next; 
    }snake_node;
    typedef struct snake_node * snake;

snake ajout_debut(snake snake,int x, int y);
void game_over(BITMAP * buffer,int score);
void draw_map(BITMAP * buffer);
void draw_menu(BITMAP * buffer);
void generate_new_apple( BITMAP * buffer,int x,int);
void move(BITMAP* buffer,snake snake,int *score);

int main()
{
BITMAP* sprite1 ;
int score=0;
snake snake;
allegro_init();
install_keyboard();
set_color_depth(16);
if(set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT,1366,768,0,0)!=0)
    {
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_TEXT,0,0,0,0);
    allegro_message("impossible %s \n",allegro_error);
    return -1;
    }
sprite1 = load_bitmap("sprite.bmp", NULL) ;
if(!sprite1) 
    {
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_TEXT, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    allegro_message("Erreur ! Impossible de lire le fichier image !");
    return 1;
    }

BITMAP * buffer=create_bitmap(1366,768);
draw_sprite(buffer, sprite1,0,0);
blit(buffer,screen,0,0,0,0,SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H);

sleep(1);



while(!key[KEY_ESC])
    {
    clear_bitmap(buffer);
    draw_menu(buffer);
        if(key[KEY_ENTER])   
        {
        clear_bitmap(buffer);
        ajout_debut(snake,500,250);
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {       
            draw_map(buffer);
            move(buffer,snake,&score);
            blit(buffer,screen,0,0,0,0,SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H);          
            }
        }           
    }
destroy_bitmap(buffer);
allegro_exit();
return 0;

}
END_OF_MAIN()

void draw_menu(BITMAP * buffer)
{
    textprintf(buffer,font,600,220,makecol(255,255,0),"       ******        ");
    textprintf(buffer,font,600,250,makecol(255,255,0),"***  START GAME  ***");
    textprintf(buffer,font,600,270,makecol(255,100,0),"    (press ENTER)   ");  
    textprintf(buffer,font,600,300,makecol(255,255,0),"***     HELP     ***");
    textprintf(buffer,font,600,320,makecol(255,100,0),"      (press H)     ");
    textprintf(buffer,font,600,350,makecol(255,255,0),"***  QUIT GAME   ***");
    textprintf(buffer,font,600,370,makecol(255,100,0),"    (press ESC)     ");
    textprintf(buffer,font,600,400,makecol(255,255,0),"       ******        ");
    //blit(buffer,screen,0,0,0,0,SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H);
}

void draw_map(BITMAP * buffer)
{
    rectfill(buffer,0,0,1366,10,makecol(255,0,0));
    rectfill(buffer,1366,0,1356,768,makecol(255,0,0));
    rectfill(buffer,1366,768,0,758,makecol(255,0,0));
    rectfill(buffer,0,0,10,768,makecol(255,0,0));
    //blit(buffer,screen,0,0,0,0,SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H);
}
void generate_new_apple( BITMAP * buffer,int x,int y)
{ 
rectfill(buffer,x,y,x+10,y+10,makecol(255,255,0));
}

void game_over(BITMAP * buffer,int score)
{
clear_bitmap(buffer);
textprintf(buffer,font,SCREEN_W/2,SCREEN_H/2,makecol(255,255,0),   "***  GAME OVER  ***");
textprintf(buffer,font,SCREEN_W/2,SCREEN_H/2+30,makecol(255,255,0),"***  SCORE :%d  ***",score);
}

snake ajout_debut(snake s,int x, int y)
{
    snake nouv;
    nouv=(snake)malloc(sizeof(snake));
    nouv->x=x+10;
    nouv->y=y+10;
    nouv->next=s;
    s=nouv; 
 return s;

}
void move(BITMAP* buffer,snake snake,int *score)
{
int applex = (int)(rand()%1336+10);
int appley = (int)(rand()%738+10);
generate_new_apple(buffer,applex,appley);
clear_keybuf();

    if (key[KEY_LEFT])
        {
        while(snake->next!=NULL)
        {
        if(snake->x > 10)
        snake->x=snake->x-1;
        else 
        game_over(buffer,score);
        }
    }
    if(key[KEY_RIGHT])
    {
        while(snake->next!=NULL)
        {
        if(snake->x < 1356)
        snake->x=snake->x+1;
        else
        game_over(buffer,score);
        }
    }
    if(key[KEY_UP])
    {
        while(snake->next!=NULL)
        {
        if(snake->y > 10)
        snake->y=snake->y-1;
        else
        snake->y=snake->y+1;
        }
    }
    if(key[KEY_DOWN])
    {
        while(snake->next!=NULL)
        {
        if(snake->y < 758)
        snake->y=snake->y+1;
        else
        game_over(buffer,score);
        }
    }
if(snake->x==applex && snake->y==appley)
{   
    rectfill(buffer,applex,appley,applex+10,appley+10,makecol(0,0,0));
    applex = (int)(rand()%1336+10);
    appley = (int)(rand()%738+10);
    generate_new_apple(buffer,applex,appley);
    snake=ajout_debut(snake,snake->x,snake->y);
    *score++;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Answer (score 2):

One issue i noticed.

Check out the compiler warning

`sanke.c:134:7: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘game_over’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]`

You have function

`void game_over(BITMAP * buffer,int score);`

you call

`game_over(buffer,score);`

inside function

`void move(BITMAP* buffer,snake snake,int *score)`

therefore you pass a pointer to int `score` in function `move` to function `game_over` which accepts as an integer.

Call `game_over (buffer, *score)` instead.

**EDIT**

A snippet:

```
    if(key[KEY_RIGHT])
    {
        while(snake->next!=NULL)
        {
        if(snake->x < 1356)
        snake->x=snake->x+1;
        else
        game_over(buffer,*score);
        }
    }
```

`while` checks for `snake->next != NULL` but it is never updated in the body, therefore this is an infinite loop.

Also debugger shows a strange negative value of `x` at the time of crash.

Suggestion: please trace it yourself.

Comment: @KhaledHoues - Extending this, you should compile with warnings enabled `-Wall`, and try to fix the code so that all of them are solved or you know exactly in each case that it's ok.

Comment: this is my first time using allegro and Ubuntu as a matter of fact and it s not as if i am an experienced developer (yesterday i discovered the linked list ) so i appreciate the help and i would be very grateful if you can explain to me this part "while checks for snake->next != NULL but it is never updated in the body, therefore this is an infinite loop.

Also debugger shows a strange negative value of x at the time of crash."

Comment: hi friends i got this error and i don't know what it means nor when does it occur : *** glibc detected *** ./prog : malloc()=memory corruption(fast) : 0x09e4db48 ***

Comment: it's not an allegro specific error, it's C language. You should try working on basic linked lists before implementing it in game.

Comment: the error basically tells you are using unallocated memory.